# whenever Click on submit of PopupForm from another view then it is showing default view(month) in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In my Application Everything Work Fine add/edit but my main Problem is IF i am on a 'agendaWeek' of Fullcalendar and try to submit or cancel the form then it is going to Month View 
Updated Code:

---

JAVASCRIPT:

```
 <script>
var globalEvent = null;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var count=0;
        var liveDate=new Date();
        var dat = new Date();
        var d = dat.getDate();
        var m = dat.getMonth();
        var y = dat.getFullYear();

            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                select: function(startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                    var startDate1=$.fullCalendar.formatDate(startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    var endDate1=$.fullCalendar.formatDate(endDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    document.getElementById('mode').innerHTML = "ADD :"+"<img src='<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/images/close.png' style='float:right; height:35px; width:35px; margin-top:-7px;' id='closeimg' name='closeimg'>";
                    document.getElementById('starting').innerHTML = startDate1;
                    document.getElementById('ending').innerHTML = endDate1;
                    $("#ginger").show();

                    $("#closeimg").click(function(){
                        $("#ginger").hide();
                    });
                    $("#eventName").focus();
                    $("#submit").click(function(){
                        var title=$("#eventName").val();
                            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',{
                                title: title,
                                start: startDate1,
                                end: endDate1,
                                allDay: false},
                            true // make the event "stick"
                            );
                            var dataString={};
                            dataString['eventName']=title;
                            dataString['startTime']=startDate1;
                            dataString['endTime']=endDate1;
                            $.ajax({
                                type : 'POST',
                                dataType : 'json',
                                url : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>data/insert',
                                data: dataString,
                                success: function(data) {
                                    alert("data insert SuccessFully1");// I get this alert
                                    var currentView = calendar.fullCalendar('getView');
                                    calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                                    calendar.fullCalendar('changeView', currentView.name)
                                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                                    calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                                    $("#ginger").hide();
                                    if(data.success){
                                                  alert("Data insert suceessfully 2");// i can't get this alert
                                    }
                                }

                            });
                    });
                },

                });

        });
</script>
```

---

CSS:

```
    body {

                font-size: 14px;
                font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
                }
        #calendar {
                width: 70%;
                margin: 0 auto;

                }
        #popup{
            padding-left: 0%; padding-top:17%; display: block; top: 0; left: 37%; z-index:1007; opacity: 1;  transform: scale(1);   
    height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width:auto;
        }
        #data{
            background-color: #ffffff;
            color:#585858;
            width:400px;
            display:block;
            z-index: 100;
            padding:0px;
            font-family: arial;
            font-weight: bold;
            border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
            border:1px solid #C5C5C5;

        }
        #popup textarea{
            width:200px;
            height:60px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            vertical-align: top;
        } 
        #detail{
/*            display: none;*/
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            z-index:1;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background-color:#000;
            filter:alpha(opacity=50);
            opacity:.5;

        }
      .mode{
            width:99%; 
            background-color: #8DB3CC;
             background-image:url("<?php echo base_url();?>assets/kendou/styles/textures/highlight.png");
            background-position: 0 center;
            background-repeat: repeat-x;
            height:30px;
            padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight:normal;
            border-bottom:1px solid #C5C5C5;
            border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
        }
        .dropdown{
            border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 2px 22px 2px 2px;
    display: block;
     cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    line-height:1px;
     border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
      color: #2E2E2E;
      border-color: #C5C5C5;
        }
```

---

HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id='calendar'></div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="ginger">
        <div id="detail"> </div>
        <form name="addData" id="addData" action="" method="post">
            <div id="popup"> 
                <div id="data"> 
                    <div id="mode" value="" class="mode">
                    <!--<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/images/close.png" style="float:right;"/>-->
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/images/logo.png">
                    </div><br>
                    <div style="padding:10px;">
                        <label for="timing">Timing: <span id="starting"></span> to <span id="ending"></span></label><br><br>
                        <label for="eventName">Description : </label>
                        <textarea name="eventName" id="eventName"type="text" value=""></textarea><br><br>
                        <label for="AgentName"><b>Agent Name*</b></label>
                        <input name="AgentName" id="AgentName"/>
                        <label for="UserName">UserName : </label>
                        <select name="UserName" id="UserName" value=""></select><br><br>
                        <input type="button"class="k-button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">//Changes here
                        <input type="reset" name="reset" class="k-button" id="reset" value="Reset">//changes here
                        <input type="button"class="k-button" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel">//changes here
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine [getView](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/getView/) and [changeView](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/changeView/):

```
//remember current view
var currentView = calendar.fullCalendar('getView');
calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
//set view type
calendar.fullCalendar('changeView', currentView.name)
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply  can u help me more i get alert("data insert succeessfully1") but i can't get alert(" data insert Successfully2"); & Now  i want to refresh Page on data.success then what i have to do?????

Comment: do you want refresh whole page or only fullcalendar content?

Comment: for track second alert problem you should debug javascript code in firebug or check errors in console

Comment: okey & i want to refresh only calendar content without pass url and In monthview each event we can see but Now  i want to add edit,delete icon before each event which is doing operation also in database

Comment: for refresh calendar content use calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); for add icons you should ask another question and explain all in detail

Comment: Ok But calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');  Not Work Properly

Comment: if you have any details or errors from browser console, please prepare new question and paste details

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28090/discussion-between-ankit-doshi-and-lukasz-koziara)